# Not able to compile Rcpp 0.12.6 under R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

When trying to compile Rcpp 12.6 with g++ 4.8.4, i'm getting the following error message:

> error: expected initializer before ‘stop’
>
> inline void noret stop(const std::string& message)

Can't seem to find anything on the attribute `NORET`.

Comment: It's probably a macro to the [[noreturn]] attribute (or some older version of it) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes  I guess you will need a more up to date g++

Comment: Close. It is an updated version of R that is missing which defines it in one of its headers.  We failed to check for this and now define it ourselves if `#ifndef NORET`.  The compilers are fine.

Comment: To add a bit more beef to this: R-devel (aka R 3.4.* to be), R-release (aka R 3.3.1 right now) and R-oldrel (aka R 3.2.5) all work.  But if you go back to R 3.1.* or older, it failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NORET` macro is defined by R -- but only in recent versions of R.  As we (and CRAN) do all our tests and builds with recent versions, this slipped.

The issue has already been reported as [issue #512](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/512) (as well as again in [#516](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/516)). It has already been addressed in the master branch as well as in an interim release 0.12.6.1 which you can obtain from the [Rcpp drat](http://rcppcore.github.io/drat/) repository.

Otherwise, just add an (empty) `#define NORET` or, better yet, update your R version.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it!